# index.php 403 in Drupal on centos 7 with SELinux enabled

Tags: centos7, drupal, http-status-code-403

i tried to install drupal on centos, i have configure my server (install httpd, mysql, php, etc) everything looks good until the last part: hit the url to install drupal

the problem here is once i hit the url/ip addr it return me 403 forbidden.

but it is weird because i put phpinfo.php at the same folder with the same group,owner and permission and i can see the page...

any idea what possibly went wrong?

Edit:
httpd error log:

> [Thu Nov 12 01:43:38.757390 2015] [core:error] [pid 2600]
>   (13)Permission denied: [client 192.168.yy.xx:53408] AH00035: access to
>   /index.php denied (filesystem path '/var/www/html/index.php') because
>   search permissions are missing on a component of the path

okay, i found the issue here, it is because the selinux enabled.
i did `setenforce 0` and it works...
but however any idea how to make this work with selinux enabled (`setenforce 1)` ?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can fix this by running `chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/html/myDrupal`. Change `/var/www/html/myDrupal` to match where your installation is located.

and plus this for a complete solution for Drupal

```
chcon -t httpd_sys_content_rw_t sites/default/
chcon -t httpd_sys_content_rw_t sites/default/settings.php
chcon -t httpd_sys_content_rw_t sites/default/files
```